# rap lyrics management

Tags: music, document-management, music-production

Suppose I'm a rapper.

I have lots of lyrics, which, half of them are not done yet, some are done, but need rework & edits, some are just a verse and need a second verse, etc... .

I also have some ideas or some trivial snippets that have hit my mind sometime, and I just wrote them down to have it.

I also have/know a beat (or maybe more than one beat candidates) for each of my songs. I may want to link to them, or upload the beat or just add information about the beat I want.

I also need to tag my lyrics & categorize them. For example tag some of my snippets as `gangsta` or categorize one of my verses in `love songs`, or tag one of my songs as `needs extra verse`, or `featuring`, etc ... .

And lots of other cool features & blah blah blah.

Maybe not the entire package I mentioned above, but is there an app/software/website that accomplishes a job similar to this?

Comment: How about using https://tiddlywiki.com/

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out & let you know in near future! +1